# Unable to covert svg to png using canvg

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, svg

I am trying to convert svg into canvas using canvg and save the converted canvas as png on my computer. 
Here is the code I am using -

```
function downloadImage()
{
    saveImage('chart1');
    saveImage('chart2');
    saveImage('chart3');
    saveImage('chart4');
    saveImage('chart5');
    saveImage('chart6');
    saveImage('chart7');
    saveImage('chart8');
}

function saveImage(chartId)
{
    var $container = $('#'+chartId),
    content = $container.html().trim();
    var canvas1 = document.createElement('canvas');
    var w=1366,h=768;
    canvas1.id     = "canvas1";
    canvas1.width  = w;
    canvas1.height = h;
    document.getElementById('pngcon').appendChild(canvas1);

    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');

    canvg(canvas, content);
    var theImage = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.id="imagepng"
    a.download = fileName+chartId+".png";
    a.href = theImage;
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    document.getElementById("imagepng").click();
    $("#pngcon").html('');

    $("#imagepng").remove();
}
```

The above code works fine and downloads all the svgs as png images but as you can see there is point of calling the saveImage() method with almost same statement 8 times. So i tried doing this using loop like -

```
function downloadImage()
   {
       for(i=1;i<=8;i++)
       {
           saveImage('chart'+i);
       }
   }
```

But this time one of the svg is missed out. I don't have any clue about what is happening here. Pls help...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Problem

The canvg method is asynchronous which means you need to use a callback approach to make this work properly.

If not, the result can be somewhat random depending on various factors such as cache, processing of the svg-to-canvas internally in canvg, how fast the browser processes the URLfor the internal image etc.

## Solution: handle asynchronous nature

First you need to modify the `saveImage()` method to take a callback:

```
function saveImage(chartId, callback) { ... }
```

Then inside it, use that callback with canvg:

```
canvg(canvas, content, {renderCallback: function() {
    var theImage = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.download = fileName+chartId+".png";
    a.href = theImage;
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();               // use the element directly instead of getting it from DOM
    $("#pngcon").html('');
    $("#imagepng").remove();

    callback();                                 // gets next image
}});
```

Now we can create a "loop" that works with this asynchronously:

```
function downloadImage(doneCallback) {
    var i = 0;                                  // accessible from within next()
    (function next() {
        if (++i < 9) {                          // increase counter, then check [1,8]
            saveImage('chart' + i, next);       // use this method as callback
        }
        else {
            if (doneCallback) doneCallback();   // when done, invoke main callback
        }
    })();                                       // self-invokes next()
}
```

You can now call the `downloadImage` with an optional callback:

```
downloadImage(function() {alert("done")})
```

However, you may want to consider whether or not to invoke the click in the same round as producing the a tag. You can add a click event handler to the a element, then invoke callback from there, but this would lead to a somewhat overcomplicated approach.

Or you can use the ID approach (just remember to use unique IDs) and iterate them and do the click() call then (from the doneCallback).

Though, this is outside the scope for this question.

Comment: Thank you so much @Ken. Did as you suggested...problem solved! :)

Comment: @ValarMorghulis great to hear. Glad it worked out :)